# about CFLAGS in Makefile

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

In a makefile, there is a line:

```
    CFLAGS += $(shell $(CC) -fno-stack-protector -E -x c /dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 
&& echo -fno-stack-protector)
```

What's the use of 
`shell $(CC) -fno-stack-protector -E -x c /dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1`?
It seems to do nothing. And how the whole line works? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your compiler *does not* have the option `-fno-stack-protector` it will return an error code (i.e. something `!=0`) otherwise it will return `0` (meaning "true" in return codes), indicating everything was all right.

Now, the expression `foo && bar` means that `bar` will only be executed if `foo` returns a non-error code (i.e. `0`). So, you see, if your compiler does *not* have that flag, it will return "false" (something `!=0`) and the `echo` command will never be executed. But if it does have the flag, `echo` will be executed.

Comment: Does `echo` append that option to CFLAGS? Why doesn't it echo to stand output?

Comment: @akirast: because `$(shell)` captures standard output - see http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Shell-Function

Answer (score 5):

It tests whether `-fno-stack-protector` is a valid command-line option for your C compiler, and if it is it then appends this option to `CFLAGS`, otherwise it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't it somehow test is -fno-stack-protector option is available?